# System settings won't open on Ubuntu 22.04: undefined symbol: gst_codec_utils_caps_get_mime_codec

Tags: gnome, settings

Suddenly I am not able to open the Setting or anything related to the setting (change wifi, connect to vpn, etc.) on my machine.

I tried some of the suggested solutions on other questions such as removing Pop ppa and reinstalling the `gnome-control-center` but didn't work and when I tried to launch the `gnome-control-center` via terminal I got below error:

```bash
$ gnome-control-center
gnome-control-center: /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-glib-1.0.so.0: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnapd-glib.so.1)
gnome-control-center: /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-glib-1.0.so.0: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgoa-backend-1.0.so.1)
gnome-control-center: /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-glib-1.0.so.0: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0)
gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: gst_codec_utils_caps_get_mime_codec
```

I tried to delete and reinstall `libwebkit2gtk` but with no success.

#### Update:

List of possible related files:

```bash
$ lsdd /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgst*
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so -> libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0 -> libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0.1701.0
356K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 354K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstallocators-1.0.so -> libgstallocators-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Sep 23 09:29 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstallocators-1.0.so.0 -> libgstallocators-1.0.so.0.1701.0
 72K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  69K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstallocators-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-1.0.so -> libgstapp-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Sep 23 09:29 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-1.0.so.0 -> libgstapp-1.0.so.0.1701.0
260K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 258K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstaudio-1.0.so -> libgstaudio-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 Sep 23 09:29 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 -> libgstaudio-1.0.so.0.1701.0
2,1M -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2,1M Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstaudio-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   23 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbadaudio-1.0.so -> libgstbadaudio-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbadaudio-1.0.so.0 -> libgstbadaudio-1.0.so.0.1701.0
224K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 221K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbadaudio-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   19 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so -> libgstbase-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Sep 23 09:29 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0 -> libgstbase-1.0.so.0.1701.0
2,1M -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2,1M Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbasecamerabinsrc-1.0.so -> libgstbasecamerabinsrc-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   38 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbasecamerabinsrc-1.0.so.0 -> libgstbasecamerabinsrc-1.0.so.0.1701.0
120K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 117K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbasecamerabinsrc-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstcheck-1.0.so -> libgstcheck-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstcheck-1.0.so.0 -> libgstcheck-1.0.so.0.1701.0
556K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 556K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstcheck-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstcodecparsers-1.0.so -> libgstcodecparsers-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstcodecparsers-1.0.so.0 -> libgstcodecparsers-1.0.so.0.1701.0
2,2M -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2,2M Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstcodecparsers-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstcodecs-1.0.so -> libgstcodecs-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstcodecs-1.0.so.0 -> libgstcodecs-1.0.so.0.1701.0
452K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 450K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstcodecs-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstcontroller-1.0.so -> libgstcontroller-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstcontroller-1.0.so.0 -> libgstcontroller-1.0.so.0.1701.0
320K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 317K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstcontroller-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstfft-1.0.so -> libgstfft-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Sep 23 09:29 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstfft-1.0.so.0 -> libgstfft-1.0.so.0.1701.0
216K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 213K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstfft-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   17 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstgl-1.0.so -> libgstgl-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24 Sep 23 09:29 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstgl-1.0.so.0 -> libgstgl-1.0.so.0.1701.0
2,1M -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2,1M Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstgl-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstinsertbin-1.0.so -> libgstinsertbin-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstinsertbin-1.0.so.0 -> libgstinsertbin-1.0.so.0.1701.0
 92K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  89K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstinsertbin-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstisoff-1.0.so -> libgstisoff-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstisoff-1.0.so.0 -> libgstisoff-1.0.so.0.1701.0
108K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 105K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstisoff-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstmpegts-1.0.so -> libgstmpegts-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstmpegts-1.0.so.0 -> libgstmpegts-1.0.so.0.1701.0
588K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 587K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstmpegts-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstnet-1.0.so -> libgstnet-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstnet-1.0.so.0 -> libgstnet-1.0.so.0.1701.0
376K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 375K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstnet-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstopencv-1.0.so -> libgstopencv-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstopencv-1.0.so.0 -> libgstopencv-1.0.so.0.1701.0
232K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 232K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstopencv-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstpbutils-1.0.so -> libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29 Sep 23 09:29 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 -> libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0.1701.0
924K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 924K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstphotography-1.0.so -> libgstphotography-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstphotography-1.0.so.0 -> libgstphotography-1.0.so.0.1701.0
 92K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  89K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstphotography-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstplayer-1.0.so -> libgstplayer-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstplayer-1.0.so.0 -> libgstplayer-1.0.so.0.1701.0
460K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 457K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstplayer-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so -> libgstreamer-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Sep 23 09:29 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 -> libgstreamer-1.0.so.0.1701.0
5,5M -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5,5M Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   19 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstriff-1.0.so -> libgstriff-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstriff-1.0.so.0 -> libgstriff-1.0.so.0.1701.0
204K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 202K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstriff-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstrtp-1.0.so -> libgstrtp-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstrtp-1.0.so.0 -> libgstrtp-1.0.so.0.1701.0
580K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 578K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstrtp-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   19 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstrtsp-1.0.so -> libgstrtsp-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstrtsp-1.0.so.0 -> libgstrtsp-1.0.so.0.1701.0
512K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 509K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstrtsp-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstrtspserver-1.0.so -> libgstrtspserver-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstrtspserver-1.0.so.0 -> libgstrtspserver-1.0.so.0.1701.0
1,8M -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1,8M Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstrtspserver-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   19 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstsctp-1.0.so -> libgstsctp-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstsctp-1.0.so.0 -> libgstsctp-1.0.so.0.1701.0
 36K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  33K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstsctp-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstsdp-1.0.so -> libgstsdp-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstsdp-1.0.so.0 -> libgstsdp-1.0.so.0.1701.0
380K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 379K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstsdp-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsttag-1.0.so -> libgsttag-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Sep 23 09:29 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsttag-1.0.so.0 -> libgsttag-1.0.so.0.1701.0
964K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 962K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsttag-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsttranscoder-1.0.so -> libgsttranscoder-1.0.so.0
136K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 134K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsttranscoder-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsturidownloader-1.0.so -> libgsturidownloader-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsturidownloader-1.0.so.0 -> libgsturidownloader-1.0.so.0.1701.0
112K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 110K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsturidownloader-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   23 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvalidate-1.0.so -> libgstvalidate-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvalidate-1.0.so.0 -> libgstvalidate-1.0.so.0.1701.0
1,7M -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1,7M Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvalidate-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   41 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvalidate-default-overrides-1.0.so -> libgstvalidate-default-overrides-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   48 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvalidate-default-overrides-1.0.so.0 -> libgstvalidate-default-overrides-1.0.so.0.1701.0
 24K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  24K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvalidate-default-overrides-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so -> libgstvideo-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 Sep 23 09:29 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 -> libgstvideo-1.0.so.0.1701.0
3,0M -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3,0M Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0.1701.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstwebrtc-1.0.so -> libgstwebrtc-1.0.so.0
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstwebrtc-1.0.so.0 -> libgstwebrtc-1.0.so.0.1701.0
192K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 192K Jun 26  2020 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstwebrtc-1.0.so.0.1701.0
```

Comment: Are you actually running Ubuntu Core 22? That is the only version of Ubuntu to use a single digit version, If this is not the case please EDIT the question with the correct version. If this is Ubuntu why would you ever have a POP ppa?

Comment: I updated the title of my question, I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: It sounds like this bug: https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg6022039.html. The suggestion there was to remove `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgst*` . Do you have any such files?

Comment: Yes, I updated my question. The link mentioned to "cleanup" those files, does it mean to delete them? I already deleted a some gst package and that disabled my desktop and I had to reinstall the desktop again.

Comment: I understand. You could first do `dpkg -S /usr/local/lib` to find out which packages install any files in `/usr/local/lib` (there are no such packages on any of my 3 Ubuntu systems though). If there is such a package, if the desktop doesn't depend on it, the issue may already be solved by removing it. Otherwise, you should be able to safely rename `x86_64-linux-gnu` to something else. Renaming it can safely be redone, even without a desktop.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that solved the issue. No package was installing anything there so I just moved the `x86_64-linux-gnu` it to my home directory and now I am able to launch the Setting again. Please post your solution so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an email exchange found [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg6022039.html), this is caused by obsolete files in `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. Very few packages install files in `/usr/local/lib` (that is not the purpose of that folder) but you may have had, at one point, reason for putting files there.

Removing those files solved the issue in OP's case. However, proceed cautiously:

1. Find out if you actually have a package that installs files in `/usr/local/lib`:

   `dpkg -S /usr/local/lib`

This will either produce a list of packages with files in that folder, or a message like `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/lib`.

2. If any packages are found, use `apt-cache rdepends [package name]` to find out if anything important depends on them.
3. Otherwise, `sudo apt remove` them. This may already solve the issue.
4. If not, rename the folder `x86_64-linux-gnu` to something else. Now the offending `libgst`* files won't be found (instead, the proper ones will be used), and `gnome-control-center` will start up normally.

In the unlikely event that the last step causes the desktop to fail, it should still be possible to restore the situating by undoing the rename action, either in a text terminal (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3-F6</kbd>), or, if even that fails, in rescue mode.